# CertCreateCertificateChainEngine throws an error in windows 7

Tags: windows, cryptography, cryptoapi, windows-api-code-pack

```
ChainConfig.cbSize = sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG);
ChainConfig.hRestrictedRoot = NULL;
ChainConfig.hRestrictedTrust = NULL;  
ChainConfig.hRestrictedOther = NULL;
ChainConfig.cAdditionalStore = 0;  
ChainConfig.rghAdditionalStore = NULL;
ChainConfig.dwFlags = CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_END_CERT;
ChainConfig.dwUrlRetrievalTimeout = 0;
ChainConfig.MaximumCachedCertificates = 0;
ChainConfig.CycleDetectionModulus = 0;

//---------------------------------------------------------
// Create the nondefault certificate chain engine.
if (CertCreateCertificateChainEngine(
        &ChainConfig,
        &hChainEngine)){
        printf("A chain engine has been created.\n");}
```

Getting error 0x80070057 (-2147024809) The parameter is incorrect, can someone help here ?

Comment: I just stumbled upon the same issue. I have searched and tried many examples and nothing works. You asked this question 5 months ago. Do you know the answer, please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

*I hope you've managed to solve this issue already. If not, here's my somewhat late answer:*

It looks like you're working with Microsoft's [example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382042(v=vs.85).aspx) for creating a certificate chain. Unfortunately it seems to be out of date; if you examine the documentation for [`CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377184(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll see that there are two more member variables that need to be initialized in Windows 7, `hExclusiveRoot` and `hExclusiveTrustedPeople`.

You could set them to NULL (if you don't need them) to take care of the error:

```
ChainConfig.hExclusiveRoot = NULL;
ChainConfig.hExclusiveTrustedPeople = NULL;
```

Comment: I use windows 7 and nothing works.I get 0x80070057, too. May you write a working example?

Comment: @QuangNHb You may need to set up your program to target the correct platform; here are a couple answers that might help you out:
[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313023/i-get-0x80070057-error-code-on-certcreatecertificatechainengine-func/34480267#34480267), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429251/vs2010-structure-change-in-cryptoapi-v7-0a-vs-v6-0a-wincrypt-h/6549295#6549295)

Comment: @frislm Thank for answering me. I use windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 to compile. I don't want to run program on windows XP. _WIN32_WINNT is equal to 0x0601.